# Change values in a dataframe if it matches a value in another row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I currently have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
           Owner        Vehicle_Color
0          James              Red
1          Peter              Green
2          James              Blue
3          Sally              Blue
4          Steven             Red
5          James              Blue
6          James              Red
7          Peter              Blue
```

Notice that `James` has two `vehicle_colors` attached to him, `Red` and `Blue`

What I am trying to do is if an owner has color `Red` for `Vehicle_Color` value anywhere along the column, replace all other values to `Red`.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: Does performance matter? A simple/naive solution would be to go through the dataframe twice: once to create an list of owners with red vehicles and then again to use that list to change the vehicle color of matching owners to red.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately that didn't work well as the overall datasize is quite large. Had to stop it running in the middle of it and come here to ask for a better solution :/

Comment: @kshikama performance is usually always preferable when working with pandas. Of course, you needn't go out of your way for performance (there's numpy for that), but any decent pandas solution can do this without having to go over `df` twice.

Comment: @NZ_DJ for closure: how much time does my answer take to run on your data? Knowing this is helpful to understand what pandas does well and why.

Comment: @coldspeed I ran with your first solution and it took about 3 seconds (around 5 million data). This is just a sample data and the actual dataset is much larger so had to find the quickest possible way. Maybe there was something I did wrong which might have took much longer than it should have when I first tried using method suggested by kshikama, still your method was faster for sure

Comment: Thanks for the info! Btw, I know groupby on the index can be upto 3 times faster than groupby on a random series. So if you need more speed, try running my second solution as well.

Comment: @coldspeed Thanks for the suggestion!! Yea my final product is going to take a lot of time with a lot of other codes running so I will try everything to cut the time down!!! Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's get rid of the lambda using `transform` + `any`:

```
m = df.Vehicle_Color.eq('Red').groupby(df.Owner).transform('any')
df.loc[m, 'Vehicle_Color'] = 'Red'
```

Or,

```
m = (    
  df.set_index('Owner')
    .Vehicle_Color
    .eq('Red')
    .groupby(level=0)
    .transform('any')
)
df.loc[m, 'Vehicle_Color'] = 'Red'
```

This should be slightly faster since the grouper is specified on `df`'s index.

```
df
    Owner Vehicle_Color
0   James           Red
1   Peter         Green
2   James           Red
3   Sally          Blue
4  Steven           Red
5   James           Red
6   James           Red
7   Peter          Blue
```

Answer (score 1):

You could

```
In [279]: df['Vehicle_Color'] = df.groupby('Owner')['Vehicle_Color'].transform(
                                         lambda x: 'Red' if 'Red' in list(x) else x)

In [280]: df
Out[280]:
    Owner Vehicle_Color
0   James           Red
1   Peter         Green
2   James           Red
3   Sally          Blue
4  Steven           Red
5   James           Red
6   James           Red
7   Peter          Blue
```